# Create function with sqlite OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create a function which I could input the genre of movies and the number of top rows I want to see.

I have already built the database with sqlite. But I don't know how to use the function input in sqlite.

My code:

```
def get_top_genre_actors(genre, k):

    c.execute('''SELECT ma.actor, m.rating FROM movie_actor ma
    LEFT JOIN movie m ON ma.imdb_id = m.imdb_id
    ORDER BY m.rating DESC, ma.actor
    LIMIT int(k)
    ''') 
    conn.commit()
    get_top = c.fetchall()

    print("Top 10 actors who played in highest rated ", genre, " movies:")
    print("Actor, Average ", genre, " movie rating")
    for x in get_top:
        print(x[0],', ', x[1],sep="")

get_top_genre_actors("Drama", 5)
```

The result I got:

> OperationalError: no such column: k

I know the wrong line is

```
LIMIT int(k)
```

How to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more recommended way is to use a parameterized query :

```
c.execute('''SELECT ma.actor, m.rating FROM movie_actor ma
    LEFT JOIN movie m ON ma.imdb_id = m.imdb_id
    ORDER BY m.rating DESC, ma.actor
    LIMIT ?
    ''', (k,))
```

This allows more security than directly formatting the values inside the query.

Note that the **second parameter *needs* to be an iterable**, that's why we use the notation for a tuple with one member `(k,)`. It could also work with a list.

BTW,  you don't need the line `conn.commit()` after a SELECT expression.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [placeholders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

```
def get_top_genre_actors(genre, k):
    c.execute('''SELECT ma.actor, m.rating FROM movie_actor ma
    LEFT JOIN movie m ON ma.imdb_id = m.imdb_id
    ORDER BY m.rating DESC, ma.actor
    LIMIT ?
    ''', (k,))
    ...
```